# How group_concate Mysql Select in one query

Tags: mysql, group-concat

My MySQL query is:

```
SELECT products_id, options_id, options_values_id FROM products_options po, products_attributes pa WHERE pa.options_id=po.products_options_id AND po.products_options_name LIKE '%Velikost%' AND po.language_id=7 group by products_id, options_values_id
```

and it gives output:

```
products_id options_id options_values_id    
3   3501    13227
3   3501    13230
4   3501    13226
4   3501    13227
4   3501    13230
4   3501    13231
5   3501    13226
5   3501    13227
5   3501    13230
5   3501    13231
6   3501    13226
6   3501    13227
6   3501    13230
6   3501    13231
```

and now I wish to have output like this:

```
3   3501 '13227, 13230'
4   3501 '13226, 13227, 13230, 13231'
5   3501 '13226, 13227, 13230, 13231'
6   3501 '13226, 13227, 13230, 13231'
```

I was trying query with group_concat

```
SELECT products_id, options_id, group_concat( options_values_id )
FROM products_options po, products_attributes pa
WHERE pa.options_id = po.products_options_id
AND po.products_options_name LIKE '%Velikost%'
AND po.language_id =7
GROUP BY products_id, options_values_id
```

but it returns:

```
products_id options_id group_concat(options_values_id)  
3   3501    13227,13227,13227
3   3501    13230,13230,13230
4   3501    13226,13226,13226
4   3501    13227,13227,13227
4   3501    13230,13230,13230
4   3501    13231,13231,13231
5   3501    13226,13226,13226
5   3501    13227,13227,13227
5   3501    13230,13230,13230
5   3501    13231,13231,13231
6   3501    13226,13226,13226
6   3501    13227,13227,13227
6   3501    13230,13230,13230
6   3501    13231,13231,13231
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: you should omit `options_values_id` from your `group by` clause, and maybe add `options_id` to it

Comment: `CONCAT('''',GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT options_values_id ORDER BY options_values_id SEPARATOR ', '),'''') AS options_values_id_str`

Comment: Reference: [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT products_id, options_id, group_concat( options_values_id )
FROM products_options po, products_attributes pa
WHERE pa.options_id = po.products_options_id
AND po.products_options_name LIKE '%Velikost%'
AND po.language_id =7
GROUP BY products_id,options_id;
```

Comment: I believe `options_id` need to be grouped too.

Comment: Oh,. Yes. I forgot that they are also duplicate :)

Comment: He's already grouping by `products_id`. The correction is to group by `options_id` instead of `options_values_id`. You have it right in the query, you just explained it wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, the problem was I forgot to use distinct. Now my query is

```
SELECT products_id, options_id, group_concat( options_values_id )
FROM products_attributes pa
WHERE pa.options_id IN (SELECT distinct products_options_id FROM products_options WHERE products_options_name LIKE '%Velikost%' AND language_id =7) 
GROUP BY  products_id, options_id
```

And now everything works fine:

```
products_id options_id group_concat( options_values_id )    
3   3501    13227,13230
4   3501    13226,13227,13230,13231
5   3501    13226,13227,13230,13231
6   3501    13226,13227,13230,13231
```